# How to sum with conditions on other columns

Tags: mysql, sql

me trying to get sum on deliveryqty with group by po number on other tables like this

```
SELECT
  po.PONumber,
  po.PODate,
  po.customername,
  po.Description,
  SUM(spb.DeliveryQty)
FROM
  tb_po AS po
LEFT OUTER JOIN
  tb_spb AS spb ON po.PONumber = spb.PONumber
GROUP BY
  po.PONumber,
  po.Description
```

and mysql show data like this

```
PONUMBER   podate      customername    description          deliveryqty
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 1500 ML      810
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 600 ML       810
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  810
4600293487 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  800
4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML      1200
4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 330 ML      1200
```

what i try is data is summed based on po number & material description not summed all qty just on po number like this :

```
PONUMBER   podate      customername    description          deliveryqty
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 1500 ML      250
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 600 ML       440
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  120
    4600293487 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  800
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML      1200
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 330 ML         0
```

here's the table i used

tb_po

```
PONUMBER   podate      customername    description          
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 1500 ML      
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 600 ML       
4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT
4600293487 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT 
4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML    
4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 330 ML
```

tb_spb

```
  PONUMBER    podate     customername    description          deliveryqty
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 1500 ML      125
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 1500 ML      125
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 600 ML       440
    4600293473 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  120
    4600293487 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  400
    4600293487 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB GALON 19 LT  400
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML      1200
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML      1200
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 240 ML      1200
    4600293489 04/04/2016 Balikpapan-CLUB AMDK CLUB 330 ML         0
```

Comment: sorry no error, me using mysql

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid SQL. MySQL prefers to return random data (they call it "indeterminate") instead of throwing an error (as every other DBMS does). http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: but i need those 2 field name, instead 1. where i can get qty from based on po number & description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this below query :-

```
 CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1 (PONumber decimal(18, 2) NOT NULL,POdate date NOT NULL,customername varchar(200) NOT NULL,description varchar(200) NOT NULL);
 INSERT INTO t1(PONumber,POdate,customername,description) 
 select distinct PONumber,POdate,customername,description from tb_po;

 select  p.PONumber,p.podate,p.customername,p.description,
(select sum(q.deliveryqty) from tb_spb q where p.PONumber=q.PONumber AND p.description = q.description) as Total
 from t1 p;

drop table t1;
```

It will give you the required output.

Comment: i tried but got error on creating temp table, any solution ? i try with 

    select (query) into #temptable

but not working

Comment: Try now I have done the required editing in the above query and tested the same in mysql environment, its working fine.