# Select distinct in temp table

Tags: mysql, sql

me trying to make distinct data in temporary table, trying to simple it with create table #tabletemp still got wrong, it says unrecognize data type near distinct and comma or closing bracket was expected near ponumber

here's the code :

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t1(
SELECT DISTINCT
  PONumber varchar(10),
  POdate varchar(10),
  customername varchar(35),
  description varchar(22)
  FROM tb_po
);

SELECT
  p.PONumber,
  p.podate,
  p.customername,
  p.description,
  (
    SELECT SUM(q.deliveryqty)
    FROM tb_spb q
    WHERE p.PONumber = q.PONumber AND p.description = q.description
  ) AS Total
  FROM t1 p
```

Comment: What are you want? please add simple input output

Comment: Is it MySql or Sql server? those are two different products.

Comment: mysql, sorry wrong tag, i'll edit it

Comment: @shamimreza here's the main problem I have too long for typed in here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37293592/how-to-sum-with-conditions-on-other-columns/37295702#37295702

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to create a temporary table to get the result that you want. Here is my revised query based on your query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  p.PONumber,
  p.POdate,
  p.customername,
  p.[description],
  SUM(q.deliveryqty)
FROM tb_po p
    INNER JOIN tb_spb q 
        ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber 
        AND p.description = q.description
GROUP BY p.PONumber,p.POdate,p.customername,p.[description]
```

Comment: it works dude thx :)

me just confuse before to make group by based on 2 column on different table :)

Answer (score 1):

If you really need it to be in a temporary table, another approach is using "SELECT INTO" wherein you wont need to declare the creation of a temporary table. (Although creating a table then inserting records is the more preferred method https://stackoverflow.com/a/6948850/6344844)

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      p.PONumber,
      p.POdate,
      p.customername,
      p.[description],
      SUM(q.deliveryqty)
INTO #TEMPTABLE_NAME
FROM tb_po p
INNER JOIN tb_spb q 
    ON p.PONumber = q.PONumber 
    AND p.description = q.description
GROUP BY p.PONumber,p.POdate,p.customername,p.[description]

SELECT * FROM #TEMPTABLE_NAME

DROP TABLE #TEMPTABLE_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first create the table then insert into the table. For SQL server You can do like this.

```
 CREATE TABLE TEMPORARY(
 PONumber varchar(10),
 POdate varchar(10),
 customername varchar(35),
 description varchar(22)
 );

insert into TEMPORARY SELECT DISTINCT
PONumber varchar(10),
POdate varchar(10),
customername varchar(35),
description varchar(22)
FROM
 tb_po ;
```

If you want to create temp table in SQL server then you have use # before table name.
For reference  http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/b19d5a/temporary-and-global-temporary-table-in-sql-server-2008/